# what makes "historical explanation" differ from "initial condition-covering law explanation"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

Does anyone have an argument that can refute the following statement?

In a deterministic world, historical explanation cannot be different from "initial condition - covering law explanation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Challenge

> Does anyone have an argument that can refute the following statement?

In a deterministic world, historical explanation cannot be different from "initial condition - covering law explanation."

## Response

It is logically possible for a world to be completely deterministic without covering laws. This is so because a completely deterministic world could be subject to *singular causation* throughout.

Here's an elaboration of how to split determinism from covering laws:

> It seems to me perfectly conceivable that a particular event causes another without
>    there being any law covering them. Imagine a universe consisting of a single particle
>    which moves around in a totally chaotic way; the particle's state SI at a certain time
>    in no way determines (not even probabilistically) its state S2 at a later time. Since by
>    assumption such a universe is totally chaotic, the particle's motion would not be law-
>    governed. Yet S1 could be the cause of S2.
>
> Indeed, Wesley Salmon's recent account of causation in terms of processes allows
>    one to be able to say just that. According to Salmon, a particle in motion is the
>    paradigm example of a causal process. What makes its motion causal is its ability to
>    carry information and its own structure, not that the motion is law-governed. Of  course, this does not mean that causal processes cannot be governed by any laws. But
>    whether they are or not is a different question from their being causal. Salmon's account enables us to speak of causal relationships without necessarily basing them on
>    any laws.
>
> A notion of causality in terms of the (continuous) evolution of states is consistent
>    with much of modern philosophy and science (perhaps with the exception of quantum
>    mechanics where the continuity seems to break down). According to Margenau and
>    van Fraassen, "Causality as evolution of states" is one of the four major conceptions
>    and a special case of "causality as physical continuity of events". They point out that
>    such a view "entails no logical difficulties and is accepted in most contemporary versions of causality" (1968, p.320). Now if "causality as evolution of states" is free of
>    logical difficulties and if the distinctive character of a causal process is its ability to
>    carry information and its own structure, then a conception of singular causation with-
>    out law is free of logical difficulties as well.
>
> A universe in which there are causal events without being determined by any law
>    is not only logically possible, but also physically realizable as well. Why should we
>    think that such a universe is determined by laws (deterministic or probabilistic) to its
>    minutest detail? Why think that there are enough laws to cover every event, every
>    state and process? As Cartwright (1983, p.19) says, God may have "the untidy mind
>    of the English"; he might have created a world in which laws are scarce. In that case
>    the Humean is committed to holding that because there are not enough covering laws,
>    the uncovered events cannot be causally related to one another. Some events then
>    must be uncaused. But it is equally plausible to hold, contra Humeans, that this event
>    caused that event but that the causal relation was not determined by any law. (Why
>    should God be that untidy?) The Humean therefore insists that the universe is either
>    completely ordered in the sense that events are causally related only if they are law-governed, or else that if there are some events which are not determined by any law
>    they must be uncaused. But surely there is a third alternative, namely, a universe in
>    which there are at least some events which are causally related even though they are
>    not law-governed. Such a universe is physically possible for the simple reason that
>    we do not have any "higher-order law" which prohibits its existence, that is, a law
>    which requires that there be a law for every cause-effect pair. Searching for covering
>    laws then is at best a methodological maxim which guides our scientific practice,
>    without carrying any ontological commitments.

(Gürol Irzik, 'Singular Causation and Law', PSA: Proceedings of the Biennial Meeting of the Philosophy of Science Association,
Vol. 1990, Volume One: Contributed Papers (1990), pp. 537-543: 537-8;  Salmon, W. C. (1984), Scientific Explanation and the Causal Structure of the World.
 Princeton: Princeton University Press; and  Cartwright, N. (1983), How the Laws of Physics Lie. Oxford: Clarendon Press.)